# Solution won't build because it can't convert from service generated type to my type

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service project that builds fine, makes an accessible WSDL, and svcutil.exe generates no errors.

I have a "Service Manager" project that access that web service, and to which I have successfully added a Service Reference ABCService.

A third project holds all the POCO objects that I need to pass back and forth - decorated liberally with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes.

When I try to build the solution, I see that Reference.cs for the ABCService has methods like this (*I have substituted (...) for the full namespaces for brevity*):

```
    public (...).Thing SaveThing((...).Thing objThing) {
        return base.Channel.SaveThing(objThing);
    }

    public (...).myCollectionOfThing0mj5ZrAW GetThings() {
        return base.Channel.GetThings();
    }
```

The first method, that returns a single Thing, works fine - but I get an error for every MyCollection method:

> Error 16  Argument 1: cannot convert from '(...).MyCollection<Thing>' to '(...).myCollectionOfThing0mj5ZrAW'

My collection class is decorated as you'd expect:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class MyCollection<T> : List<T> where T : BaseType
{
  //  ...
}
```

I have no idea why it's generating the funky "myCollectionOfThing0mj5ZrAW" name, or why the translation from one to the other is failing

**EDIT 1:** 
I have tried using

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name= "myCollection{0}", ItemName = "{0}")]
```

to decorate my collection class, and I get the same error but with updated names:

> Error  12  Argument 1: cannot convert from '(...).myCollection<(...).Thing>'
>    to '(...).myCollectionThing'

**EDIT 2:**

Despite having checked the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies", selected the radio button for "specified referenced assemblies", and checking the box next to my POCO assembly:
[image: Screenshot of reusing referenced assemblies]

...the service reference is STILL being generated with unique class names:

[image]

Comment: When running svcutil, did you use the `/reference` parameter to point it to the DLL with your data contract classes?

Comment: It sounds like the tool is generating the types. Do you have 'reuse types in all references assemblies checked'?

Comment: @RitchMelton I definitely have "reuse types" checked, and I've selected the assembly ... although I was having trouble with it importing a second version of my assembly earlier - how can I make sure it's referencing the right version?  Could the version be the problem?

Comment: @vesan I don't think so - I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Are you adding reference from `bin` or `debug` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @vesan & @RitchMelton in comments, it seems types are regenerated at client and you should **reuse** the `DataContract`.

If you are adding service reference, reuse the type in referenced assemblies by selecting radio`reuse types in all references assemblies`:
[image]

Also note you might need to change collection type to `System.Collection.Generic.List` to prevent changing of List to Arrays/

If you are generating proxy using SvcUtil, you need to use `/reference:` to reuse `DataContract` assemblies while generating reference like:

```
svcutil /reference:YourDLL.dll http://localhost/YourService?wsdl
```

For more details on `/refernce` with `SvcUtil`refer:

[ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

[svcutil exlude/reuse refrenced assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786096/svcutil-exlude-reuse-refrenced-assemblies)

Comment: Please see edit 2 - despite configuring it as you describe, the service reference is still generating unique classes.