# Call a Java Soap Web Service Method with object parameter from C# Client

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, ssis-2012

I want to pass list of Object as the input to the web service.
I came to know we cannot achieve this using the built in Web Service task in SSIS. So I tried calling it through script task which uses C# Code. 
I am able to call a Java Web Service(SOAP) through script Task. 
I am able to test by passing simple parameters like string to the web service method.
Now I want to pass list of objects as parameter to the Web service method.
For testing purpose first I tried passing a object. The class in the c# client is as below

```
  [Serializable]
        public class Person
        {
            public string _PersonName;
            public string _PersonNumber;
            public string _Password;
            public bool _isTrue;
            public List<string> _configs;
            public Person()
            {
            }

            public Person(string PersonName, string PersonNumber, string Password, bool val)
            {
                _PersonName = PersonName;
                _PersonNumber = PersonNumber;
                _Password = Password;
                _isTrue = val;
                // _configs = config;        
            }
        }
```

The corresponding proxy client class is as below

```
public partial class person {

        private string _PersonNameField;

        private string _PersonNumberField;

        private string _PasswordField;

        private bool _isTrueField;

        private string[] _configsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string _PersonName {
            get {
                return this._PersonNameField;
            }
            set {
                this._PersonNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string _PersonNumber {
            get {
                return this._PersonNumberField;
            }
            set {
                this._PersonNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string _Password {
            get {
                return this._PasswordField;
            }
            set {
                this._PasswordField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bool _isTrue {
            get {
                return this._isTrueField;
            }
            set {
                this._isTrueField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("_configs", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
        public string[] _configs {
            get {
                return this._configsField;
            }
            set {
                this._configsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The method in the proxy class is below

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://sample.xyz.abc.ext/", ResponseNamespace="http://sample.xyz.abc.ext/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string createPerson([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] person arg0) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("createJigBoard", new object[] {
                        arg0});
            return ((string)(results[0]));
        }
```

I am calling the method in the client as below

```
ServiceReference.TestService per = new ServiceReference.TestService();
 var testList=new List<string>();
 Person personOne = new Person("Manoj", "123456761", "Administrator", true,testList);
            NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("person", "person");
            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri("http://pcblr********:80/*******/servlet/TestService"), "Basic", myCred);            
            StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));          
            xmlSer.Serialize(textWriter, personOne);
                       textWriter.Close();
            per.createPerson(personOne);
```

I am getting the error

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Client.Person' to 'Proxyclass.person'  ******\ScriptMain.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct. The service expects a ProxyClass.person but you are sending a Client.Person.

Instead of this line:

```
Person personOne = new Person("Manoj", "123456761", "Administrator", true,testList);
```

you should create a ProxyClass.person-object and map the parameters manually or use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or similar.

You also need to change serialization from

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
```

to

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProxyClass.person));
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I am able to pass single object .. I want to pass list<object> but it is treating as object array. I changed the settings as below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621993/solution-wont-build-because-it-cant-convert-from-service-generated-type-to-my

Comment: Web service automatically will take care of serializing. List.ToArray() works fine.